# How to (simulate) a POST in jUnit

Tags: post, junit, playframework

I am trying to have a server respond to a request which needs a XML structure. The easiest way I thought would be to create a POST with a string containing the XML, using the Play Framework.

However, I cannot seem to get it to work. I am calling the test with the following code:

```
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put("data", xmlString);
    Http.Response response = POST("/server/", map);
```

When on the server checking the parameters it is not in it as it returns false:

```
     params._contains("data")
```

Comment: in your case, if the server awaits XML and you send data=SOME_XML, it's not XML, isn't it?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. I don't mind what the best way is to sent it, just a mechanism to sent XML to the server, using normal http operation to keep it simple. The xmlstring contains the DOM rendered to a string. Maybe my question should be more fundamental, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: mandubian is asking if the xml should be a parameter, or the body of the request.

Comment: Ok, well, I think I show my ignorance here (as this is the first time I try to do this, so far I have just put parameters in the address path, but now I need more sophisticated communication). I have to look at how to but it in the body then I guess

Comment: Sending XML in a request parameter is not really advised or if it's really really short. The XML is generally sent directly in the post body and thus, it won't appear in the request parameters. Read a few things and I think you should find the solution by yourself ;)

Comment: Thanks Mandublan, this is something new to me in Java and I was trying to do it the same as I have done in PHP in the past. I will dig a bit deeper with your hints! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I think it will help if you can post the whole code. e.g. Whether you are using FunctionalTest, and how you do the check in server side.